# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError in chrome console

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am using a fetch in my chrome console. But its throwing `"VM4253:1          Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch at <anonymous>:1:1"`  error.

Below is the code:

```
url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&appid=MY_APP_ID";
fetch(url).then( (response) => response.json() ).then( (data) => console.log(data) );
```

Surprisingly same code is running fine when I run my react app(of which this code is part of).

I would really appreciate help.

Thanks.

Comment: is there an error before that error that would explain this error?

Comment: it just says failed to fetch

Comment: try in firefox - firefox dev tools actually help

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code In case the promise rejects, we will handle the error using the .catch() like so:

Also, we have to make the fetch request on the use effect

```
useEffect(() => {
 fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&appid=MY_APP_ID')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((actualData) => console.log(actualData))
  .catch((err) => {
   console.log(err.message);
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: it says failed to fetch

Comment: You have to check your endpoint or maybe the app id. also try your actual endpoint in Postman then you will come to know the response.